# Matlab - How to implement backward Euler's method?

Tags: matlab, iteration, sparse-matrix

I am trying to implement these formulas:

#### Forward Euler's method:

[image]

this is what I have tried:

```matlab
x_new = (speye(nv)+ dt * lambda * L) * x_old;
```

Is there anything wrong with this? How can I calculate this using **sparse** operation?

#### Backward Euler's method:

[image]

I have tried this:

```matlab
x_new = (speye(nv)- dt * lambda * L) \ x_old;
```

How to implement the backward part where the existing `x` is calculated based on the new `x`? Is it OK to use division?

---

`L` is a sparse matrix like this:

```matlab
full(L) =

   -1.0000    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.3333   -1.0000    0.3333         0    0.3333
    0.3333    0.3333   -1.0000    0.3333         0
    0.3333         0    0.3333   -1.0000    0.3333
    0.3333    0.3333         0    0.3333   -1.0000
```

also for other variable we have something like this:

```matlab
nv = 5;
dt = 0.01;
lambda = 0.5;

x_old =   [-4 0 5;
            1 -5 5;
            1 0 1;
            1 5 5;
            1 0 0]
```

Comment: Re: "_Is it OK to use division?_" - Surely you have some test problem with which you can compare results, right?

Comment: Yes, the result seems fine, except for the zero elements in the denominator. Also, my question is: is it allowed to use division in the Euler's forward method or is there a way to keep the formula as it is without moving `(speye(nv)- dt * lambda * L)` to the other side? and do I need to use `.*` instead of `*` anywhere?

Comment: To me, you look to be doing it correctly. A numerical method with any level of implicitness (i.e., the solution of a system of equations is needed to calculate new values) requires computation. The code `x_new=A\x_old` is in fact solving the linear system for `x_new` and is not just a simple division operation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the domain here but the Backward Euler method is a basic ordinary differential equation solver.

There are two approaches how to solve the situation when `x_new` stands on both sides of the equation.

## 1. [Fixed point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration)

You use `x_new_temp` and you set `x_new_temp` as `x_old` for the first iteration and do few iterations with the Forward Euler formula. After the iterations perhaps limited by some difference between `x_new_temp` from iteration `i` and `i-1`, you set `x_new` as `x_new_temp` from the last iteration.

## 2. Solve non-linear equation with appropriate method, e.g. [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

The Backward Euler formula dictates:

`y_new = y_old + k*f(t,y_old)`

We can transform this into:

`y_old + k*f(t,y_old) - y_new = 0`

This is a basic non-linear function which can be solved with any numerical method intended to solve this type of problem.

**In your case** when matrix are involved, I would go with the fixed point iteration.